# Is there a fix for the ClassNotFoundException happening on startup on Google App Engine standard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a Java 11 app using legacy bundled services that was deploying fine until yesterday. Seemingly with no changes whatsoever, the app now encounters an exception on startup and fails to start entirely.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Failed startup of context c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext@61a117bd{/,file:///workspace/,UNAVAILABLE}{/workspace}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerFactory.doCreateHandler(AppVersionHandlerFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerFactory.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:82)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:264)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:229)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer.<clinit>(JettyJasperInitializer.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.<init>(ContainerInitializer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.quickstart.QuickStartDescriptorProcessor.visitContextParam(QuickStartDescriptorProcessor.java:187)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log
    at org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog.<init>(JuliLog.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApplicationClassLoader.findClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 39 more
```

I've tried:

- Deploying the exact commit hash that previously worked
- Deploying via Clould Build
- Deploying via IntelliJ

Comment: Did you fill an issue about that to the support? There are release every weeks (tuesday/wednesday usually) and it could be a bug on Google Side

Comment: Same here. Still struggling to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I didn't file an issue, but I did +1 this one that I just found: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301222147

Answer (score 2):

we have encountered the exact same issue.

The solution that worked for us involved removing all static files in the webapp folder — I suspect the cause was the JSP files.

In the stack trace, you can observe that those errors are somehow related to JSP: org.eclipse.jetty.apache.**jsp**.JuliLog.
We were fortunate that those files were no longer in use, and I understand that removing them can be problematic, but it might be worth a try.

We also raised a ticket but have yet to receive a response.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Thanks for the tip. I heavily use static files in the webapp folder, so this isn't really an option for me without major refactoring, but if this isn't fixed soon, I might have to get to it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully deploy new versions by adding the following to my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.52.v20230823</version>
</dependency>
```

Obviously this is not an ideal solution, so I hope Google fixes whatever it is that they broke.

Comment: This fixed my problem too. 09/22/2023 9:53 PM MT